# 401 error: unable to access start page of IIS website with accessType="Allow" users="?"

Tags: iis-10

Anonymous Authentication is enabled on the Authentication dialog and IIS_IUSRS have `read & execute` on the website folder, but I'm unable to access website with the web.config shown below. When I type `http://servername` I get the following error:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
                 
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I had added an application beneath the website and  set up a role-based authorization for it using a AD Security Group, but I've since removed that application.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, `*` means all users and `?` means anonymous users. the above section allows anonymous users to allow the website, in other words, there are no authenticated rules for anonymous users. On my side, the website with `Anonymous Authentcation` mode enabled and with the above settings works properly. I doubt if there is a local cache in your browser or some problem with the website project.
[image]
Please confirm the issue by applying the configuration in the default IIS website.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I gave anonymous users access using the Authorization Rule but without success.  I was finally able to get the site working by giving the "Everyone" entity ACL read&execute permissions on `wwwroot`.

Comment: Congragulations, the Read/Write permisson of the website root folder is required for hosting a website. Try to grant IUsr account to ACL of the website root folder.

Comment: IIS_IUSRS did already have read&execute on the wwwroot.  That was the mystery. I did not understand why the "Everyone" group needed permission.  I had installed the URL authentication security feature and restarted IIS. Could that security feature be involved?

Comment: yes, this feature may interfere with the Read/Write permission of the website file/folder. you can configure it by using the above UI.